# Save as Tex \(\(f(x))\)\) double \('s problem

Tags: latex

a simple example
Text Cell Style with a inline Cell (DisplayFormula)

```
Cell[TextData[{"inline mode ",Cell[BoxData[FormBox[RowBox[{"f", "(", "x", ")"}], TraditionalForm]], "DisplayFormula", FormatType->"TraditionalForm"], " "}], "Text"]
```

setting in Options `DefaultNewInlineCellStyle` is `DisplayFormula`.

If setting in Options `DefaultNewInlineCellStyle` is `Text` this would not happen.

I think someone would also encounter the situation: Converting between TraditinalForm and StandardForm sometimes auto-add or remove some ().

When copy as Latex, it's ok to compile in WinEdt(my tex compiler‘s access)

```
f \text{inline} \text{mode} x

f(x)

\text{Null}
```

but when save notebook as .tex, load in file `f(x)` becomes

```
\(\(f(x)\)\)
```

The right should be

```
\(f(x)\)
```

[image]

---

I asked on [the TeX StackExchange site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121552/fx-double-s-problem?noredirect=1#comment271484_121552) and got some comments"

> I am not on the other site, but in your *Mathematica* set-up it does not make much sense to say that inline should be rendered as `DisplayFormula`. My guess is the converter used to output `$…$` for inline math and `$$…$$` for display. Now `\(…\)` is often to be preferred for inline, but the display equivalent is `\[…\]` not `\(\(…\)\)`. – [Andrew Swann](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/15925/andrew-swann)

This is a good point.

`DisplayFormula` ==> `$$`
`InlineFormula` ==> `$`

This is MathJax.

However, maybe the same to `\(`.

As Silvia's former suggestion, I should just not use `DisplayFormula` in inline cells.

But I still need to check: would some other inline styles generate such double `\(`s?

Comment: OT: WinEdt is an editor/IDE, not a TeX compiler.

Comment: @Silvia yeah, you're right. If I use CCompiler in Mathematica, I would probably say: When I open Mathematica(my C Compiler)...it's much simpler in my opinion,anyway I added an access in the post.

Comment: I think you simply should not use `DisplayFormula` for inline formula.. Just like you should not use $$\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$ for inline formula in LaTeX.

Comment: @Silvia en, seems the double \(\( ' problem is not because of `DisplayFormula` which really not so necessary. But I'm not sure about this question, I should take time to do more tries.

Comment: @Silvia In the previous simple case, I now accept your suggestion not use `DisplayFormula` in inline cells. Though still need to keep the track of whether other styles would generate such double `\(`s

Comment: I guess this would be a similar problem to [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29356/mathematica-inserts-extra-left-and-right-for-absolute-values-in-latex-output)?

Comment: @LeoFang Has some similarities, but this question seems could be omitted when we do not choose the use of `DisplayFormula` in inline cells.

Comment: I see. Oh btw, I didn't notice that it's you posting that question...my fault!

Answer (score 2):

When you Copy as LaTeX from the Edit menu, the assumption is that your highlighted expression is mathematics.  The result is just the stuff that goes *between* the LaTeX delimiters.  You're expected to place them between dollar signs or double dollar signs or whatever you want to use yourself.

Note that this is similar to the behavior of `TeXForm`:

```
TeXForm[Integrate[f[x], x]]

(* Out: \int f(x) \, dx *)
```

By contrast, `Export` to TeX generates an entire LaTeX document, which includes delimiters.

```
ExportString[Integrate[f[x], x], "TeX"]

(* Out:
%% AMS-LaTeX Created by Wolfram Mathematica 9.0 : www.wolfram.com

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}

\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}

\newcounter{mathematicapage}
\begin{document}

\[\int f[x] \, dx\]

\end{document}
*)
```

Finally, we can now see why the "inline" and the "mode" were included in LaTeX \text commands - because that's necessary to have the display as text inside the LaTeX delimiters that you are expected to provide.