# Mathematica inserts extra \left and \right for absolute values in LaTeX output

Tags: export, latex

Type the following in a *Mathematica* DisplayFormula cell(other styles may also encounter this problem):
<kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>$l$</kbd>+<kbd>|</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>$r$</kbd>+<kbd>|</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, and save as LaTeX.

### Note: See the difference of the character between | |.

$z$ and $z_1$, $|z|$, $|z_1|$

```
Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", 
 SubscriptBox["z", "1"], "\[RightBracketingBar]"}]], "DisplayFormula"]
```

with subscript, then...

*Mathematica* inserts extra `\left` and `\right` for absolute values in the LaTeX output:

```tex
%% AMS-LaTeX Created by Wolfram Mathematica 9.0 : www.wolfram.com
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}
\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}
\newcounter{mathematicapage}

\begin{document}
\[
\left\left| Z_1+Z_2\right\right| \leq \left\left| Z_1\right\right| +\left\left| Z_2\right\right|
\]
\end{document}
```

What should I do to get valid output that LaTeX will accept?

Comment: Please provide the original code that was converted and some info on how this was done to clarify your question and enable reproduction.

Comment: @YvesKlett here, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29314/choose-the-use-of-vertical-bar-indicate-absolute-value

Comment: My preference is to have self-contained questions / MWEs...

Comment: @YvesKlett fine,,,since this question was asked in Tex.SE,...and that was asked in Math.SE...You can type Esc l|Esc and Esc r| Esc in one `DisplayFormula` cell.

Answer (score 4):

You may run this

```
StringReplace[string, {"\\left\\left" -> "\\left", "\\right\\right" -> "\\right"}]
```

on your $\LaTeX$ output. I am surprised this bug is still here 3 years after.