# TeXForm of Abs[a^n] is not valid TeX, known error?

Tags: bugs, latex

```
In[116]:= Abs[a^n] // TeXForm                                                   

Out[116]//TeXForm= \left\left| a^n\right\right|
```

But the result isn't valid TeX. It won't work here:

$\left\left| a^n\right\right|$

or on texpaste.com, where the error is "Missing or unrecognized delimiter for \left".

Is this a known bug and is there a known workaround?

OK, it turns out the workaround is to just remove the spurious `\left` and `\right`, so that `\left| a^n\right|` works fine:

$\left| a^n\right|$

However, not sure if this workaround works in general, or just in this simple case.

```
In[49]:= $Version                                                               

Out[49]= 9.0 for Linux x86 (32-bit) (November 20, 2012)
```

Comment: This looks like a bug to me.  You should edit your question to include the Mathematica version and the OS you're using.  I can reproduce the bug in MM 10.2.0.0 under Mac OS 10.10.5

Comment: Please note that TeXForm produces AMS-LaTeX-compatible TeX output. This is documented in the "Details" section of the TeXForm documentation. In LaTeX, \left and \right are used for delimiters when they have to change the size dynamically depending on the content.

Comment: @ArnoudBuzing The issue here is `\left\left`, not just `\left` which should be fine. Can `\left` be followed by another `\left` in AMS-LaTeX? In other words, `\left` is being used as a delimiter for another `\left` which is probably wrong. You need `\left(something)` not `\left\left`

Comment: It seemed to be fine when I tried your example here: https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php. But you're right that it looks wrong (and probably is wrong in general).

Comment: When I tried |a^n| on that site, it says the LaTeX version is `\[|a^n|\]`?

Comment: I found an open ticket on this issue. I have added you as a reporter and added a link to this post. Another case is TeXForm[Abs[r+1/2]]

Comment: `\left\left|` is most definitely invalid LaTeX.  Any `\left` (or `\right`) should be followed by a delimiter or by `.`, otherwise LaTeX complains and halts.

Comment: OK, I have a possible fix for this (basically TeXForm needs to have better support for TemplateBox[..., "Abs" ]. I will include it as an answer below. Please try it out. If this solution looks useful, I will suggest including this fix.

Comment: This is old hat. It has been reported in at least three posts: [54857](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54857/possible-bug-in-mathematica-texform-generating-left-left),
[76839](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76839/copy-as-latex-error) and [29356](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29356/mathematica-inserts-extra-left-and-right-for-absolute-values-in-latex-output). The first one also contains a solution.

Comment: ok, I think this one can be closed then. I do think adding proper support for TemplateBox[..., "Abs" ] is the correct solution here. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

(Please see comment section above)

Barry, please evaluate this code below and then try any `TeXForm` that uses `Abs` that you may have:

```
System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex[
 TemplateBox[{System`Convert`CommonDump`n_}, "Abs", ___]
] := "\\left| " <> 
 System`Convert`TeXFormDump`MakeTeX[System`Convert`CommonDump`n] <> 
 " \\right|"
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked and I've added it to my initfile.